# How to count distinct values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, export-to-excel

Input

[image]

I need Summary like below

[image]

I am looking for distinct no of account here instead of duplicate.

Comment: Use a Pivot-table.

Comment: You can use a formula like: `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A11,1,B2:B11,B2:B11))` replacing the 1 with a cell reference if preferred.

Comment: This isn't a question best answered here. Pose exactly the same, word for word, to Google and you will get a much better result, meaning many more choices, each with a complete explanation.

Comment: @Rory I'm getting #DIV/0!. Can you try your end

Comment: I did test before posting. If you get that error, nothing matches the criteria so presumably your ranges are wrong, or you mistyped something.

Comment: I wrapped @Rory's inner formula in an `IFERROR` statement to get rid of the `#DIV/0!`s. But it provides wrong results if an **Acc No** entry is featured in more than one **Br Code** group. This happens with *301* which is part of *3* and *4*.

Comment: @BalaS: Please review my revised answer, which now takes into account that you are using **Excel 2007**

Answer (score 0):

You can `FILTER` the original data and then count the number of unique instances.

Try `=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$10, $B$2:$B$10=$D2)))`

Here I assume that the original data is in cells A2:B10, and that the criteria for the filtering is in column D.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have updated my answer to work for **Office 2007** and mixed @Rory's comment to original post with my `OFFSET` part of my previous Office 365 solution.

### Formula

Plase the following formula in `E2`:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIFS(OFFSET($A$3,MATCH(D3,$A$3:$A$12,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A$3:$A$12,D3),1),OFFSET($A$3,MATCH(D3,$A$3:$A$12,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A$3:$A$12,D3),1)))
```

### Explanation

- The `OFFSET`part provides a list of consecutive rows that feature the `Acc No` and belong to the same *Br code*. It uses `MATCH`to determine the first occurance of the given *Br code*. As the **anchor** cell for the formula is the cell with the first content (`$A$3`), I subtract 1 from the `MATCH` result. To determine the height, I use a `COUNTIF` statement, that counts how many rows feature the current *Br code*.
- The cell range provided by `OFFSET` is then used as input for @Rory's `COUNTIFS` solution.

Comment: The OP specifically tags Excel 2007 where your formula won't work.

Comment: @Rory: Thanks for pointing it out. I have overlooked the tag. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The text and non-text (numeric) unique and distinct values in the column are quickly listed separately using VBA macro.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqH9L.gif)

```
Sub GetCountDistinctValues()
 Dim sayi As Long, rang As Range
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each rang In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If rang <> Empty Then
                If Not .Exists(rang.Value) Then
                    .Add rang.Value, Nothing
                    If IsNumeric(rang.Value) Then sayi = sayi + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Range("C2").Value = .Count - sayi
        Range("C3").Value = sayi
    End With
    End Sub
```

Source : [Find count of unique-distinct values](https://eksi30.com/useful-macros-1-get-count-of-unique-values/)